# Unable to import or add row from a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I am trying to add a row acquired from a database to a DataTable.
First I tried Using `bucketdt.Rows.Add(r);` I got an error saying *Row belongs to another Table*
Then I used `bucketdt.ImportRow(r);` then it doesn't copy the row at all!

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //DataTable f = new DataTable();
        dosObject = new DataOperations();
        bucketdt = new DataTable();
        count=0;
        foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
        {
            string val = Session[key].ToString();
            DataRow r = bucketdt.NewRow();
            r = dosObject.SubCategoryDetails2(Convert.ToInt16(val)).Rows[0];
            bucketdt.ImportRow(r);
            bucketdt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        GridView1.Enabled = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = bucketdt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
```

am I missing something?

Now I tried adapting the code as told by @wonko79

```
 DataTable f = new DataTable();
        dosObject = new DataOperations();
        bucketdt = new DataTable();
        count=0;
        foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
        {
            string val = Session[key].ToString();

            DataRow r = bucketdt.NewRow();
            f = dosObject.SubCategoryDetails2(Convert.ToInt16(val));
            r["Id"]=f.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            r["SubCategoryName"] = f.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            r["Make"] = f.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            r["Cost"] = f.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            //bucketdt.ImportRow(r);
            bucketdt.Rows.Add(r);
            bucketdt.AcceptChanges();
```

n now it says the row doesnt contain Column: 'Id' does not belong to table .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your DataRow r which follows the schema of bucketdt with a DataRow folowing another schema.

```
DataRow r = bucketdt.NewRow();
        r = dosObject.SubCategoryDetails2(Convert.ToInt16(val)).Rows[0]; // overwrites r with a DataRow following another schema
```

Comment: So should I copy each item seperately?

Comment: Yes. Or you can wrap the filed mapping and queries with a [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx).

Comment: please take note of the edits!, Sorry to bother you , but Ive encountered yet another error!

Comment: Well, as the error message tells you it seems that your table bucketdt does not contain a coulumn named "Id" (maybe ID or id?). Also take note that you should only ask one question per thread.

Comment: Oh is that so? But then plz guide me to overcome this one! DataGridView is way easy than GridView :(